# Output of model.predict_generator()]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am new to Keras and i have a question. When i run predict_generator on my test dataset i get weird output. How can i get number between 0 and 1?

```
model.predict_generator(generator=test_generator, verbose = 1)
```

And when i try it i get someting like this.

```
       [9.11257455100e-01, 1.11224177e-01, 6.96873654e-03, 6.45312342e-01,
```

How i provided my train data:

Basically i have 5 folder lets say named A,B,C,D,E and every folder has full of pictures related to its category name.

```
datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale = 1./255, 
        validation_split=0.2, 
        featurewise_center=False, 
        samplewise_center=False,  
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  
        zca_whitening=False,  
        zoom_range = 0.1,
        width_shift_range=0.1, 
        height_shift_range=0.2,  
   
       )
```

And finally:

```
hist = model.fit_generator(
                     train_generator,
                     epochs=100,
                     shuffle = True,
                     validation_data= validation_generator,
                     steps_per_epoch = 64,
                     verbose = 1
                     )
```

Comment: Those are numbers between zero and one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not as complicated as it seems. When you run model predict it makes a predictionon each input sample. Each row in the array corresponds to a prediction for a sample. Now the number of columns in the array is equal to the number of classes your model was  trained on which in your case looks to be 5 classes. The number in the column is the probability that the sample is in the class represented by the row. For example in the first row of the matrix the value of 2.30657243e-10 represents the probability that the sample belongs to class 1. The value 4.47556471e-11 in column 2 represents the probability that sample 1 belongs to class 2 etc. The value 1.00000000e+00 in column 4 means there is essentially a 100% probability the sample belongs in class 4. The data in the next row is similarly structured for the second sample. To find the most probable class you use np.argmax to find the column with the highest probability to get the most likely prediction for the class. To make the printed result more readable use the code below

```
preds=model.predict_generator(generator=test_generator, verbose = 1)
preds=preds.round(decimals=2)
for p in preds:
    print (p)
```

I am assuming you used the ImageDataGenerator to create your test samples. If you did here is how to print out your results clearly.

```
test_file_names=test_gen.filenames  # sequential list of name of test files of each sample
test_labels=test_gen.labels # is a sequential list  of test labels for each image sample
class_dict= test_gen.class_indices # a dictionary where key is the class name and value is the corresponding label for the class
print (class_dict) # have a look at the dictionary
new_dict={} 
for key in class_dict: # set key in new_dict to value in class_dict and value in new_dict to key in class_dict
    value=class_dict[key]
    new_dict[value]=key
print('PREDICTED CLASS  TRUE CLASS       FILENAME ' ) # adjust spacing based on your class names
for i, p in enumerate(preds):
    pred_index=np.argmax(p) # get the index that has the highest probability
    pred_class=new_dict[pred_index]  # find the predicted class based on the index
    true_class=new_dict[test_labels[i]] # use the test label to get the true class of the test file
    file=test_file_names[i]
    print(f'    {pred_class}       {true_class}       {file}')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. for this answer. It makes much more sense right now. Is there anyway to get result between 0 and 1 instead of these weird number to make it more readeble?

Comment: see amended answer

Comment: Can i ask you one more question if you dont mind.. Thanks to you the output is much clear right now. I also would like to see the prediction outputt classes. For example in one row i get this.[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]. So i want to see what value 1 represents. As you said i have 5 classes so which one it belongs to? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It depends on how you provided the training data. Without that I can't tell

Comment: I have editted the question to show you how i provided traning data. Thank you

Comment: see amended answer

Comment: Damn. Thank you very much for this. You are the best. One more problem. I am having an errror which is  'ImageDataGenerator' object has no attribute 'filename . Could please tell me which version are u using? I have searchin the solution but couldn't find it. Thank you again..

Comment: Tensorflow 2.1.0. filenames and labels are attributes of ImageDataGenerator so I do not know why it is not working for you. If your generator is named test_gen then test_gen.filenames should give you a list of file names.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. Really appreciated. After i run this code i saw that my network is really bad at predicting data which i can not understand why. I have really good accuracy for accuracy for test and valiaditon data. So i asked a new question which is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64476565/good-training-accuracy-and-validaiton-accuracy-but-poor-prediction-accuracy.  Thank you very much