# Good training accuracy and validaiton accuracy but poor prediction accuracy

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am having a nonsense problem with my CNN. It has good accuracy on test and validation data but when it comes to prediction it is really bad and i couldn't figure it out why.

I have a folder which contains traningData and TestData and each folder has 5 sub folder names classA, classB. classC, classD, classE. All of them has related pictures.

-----SOLUTION TO THIS QUESTION---------
i have found the mistake thats why i cleared my question to make it much clears. So the problem as in the test_generator. I didnt put shuffle=False,
so you have to put shuffle=False when you do test_datagen.flow_from_directory() so the samples don't get shuffled and have the same order when you predict it

Thank you very much for everyone

```
test_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(    
        rescale = 1./255,
        )

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory="../newFlowers/TestData",
        target_size=(128, 128),
        color_mode="rgb",
        batch_size=8,
        class_mode="categorical",
        

    )
```

Comment: Does your test data have the same distribution as train/validation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting

Comment: This doesn't look like a code problem, so much as a CNN optimisation problem. You would need to provide considerably more information in order to attempt to troubleshoot this (network structure, training data makeup and whether this is accounted for, batch size, data shuffling between epochs?, batch normalisation?, etc.)

Comment: Okey let me share it

Comment: i have added all the info.

Comment: Are you rescaling you data before making predictions?

Comment: i have already rescaled them in the test_datagen

Comment: in evaluate_generator you have verbose=3 it should be either 0 or 1

Comment: The predicted probabilities are correct. You have the wrong label order when doing class prediction.

Comment: Thank you all everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your evaluation accuracy is 89.9%. I tested the code I gave you to print the results and they were correct for the model and data I was using. Please show the code you used for model.predict. Should be like below. DO not use predict-generator  fit_generator or evaluate_generator as the will be depreciated in future versions of tensorflow. Just use fit, predict or evaluate.

```
length=len(labels)
test_steps=  int(length/batch_size) +1
preds=model.predict(test_gen,  verbose=0, steps=test_steps)
```

Looking at your preds print out the first prediction should have been for index=4 which is class E so that is correct, second prediction index with highest probability is 1 which is class B so that is correct, so are the rest. Are you sure you have the labels as labels=test_gen.labels

Comment: test_labels=test_generator.labels  yep

Comment: Found the solution and explained it Thank you very much

Comment: You have been so helpful. Thank you very much and have a good day.